# passing properties to react component empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an issue regarding react and I was hoping i could get some help. I will try my best to explain my situation and i will provide examples where needed.

The situation:

I have this component:

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Ui from './UI';


function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [query, setQuery] = useState({query : ''});


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query.query}&units=metric&appid=appid`)
        .then(res => {
            setWeather({data: res.data})

        });

  };


  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuery({query:e.target.value});
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" onChange = {handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit" value = 'Search!'/>
        </form>

        <Ui weather ={weather}/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's fetching data from the openweather API. When everything is set, I pass the Weather data to the presentational component named "Ui".

The data weather object that i pass down to the Ui has properties. One of these properties looks like 'weather.data.main'. When I try to access this in my presentational component I get an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

But i am sure main exists. How is this possible ?

here's my presentational component :

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Ui(weather) {
    console.log(weather.data.main);
    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Ui;
```

Comment: `weather` is `undefined` until the AJAX call is completed; Using `weather && <Ui weather ={weather}/>` should fix it

Comment: `const [weather, setWeather] = useState({data: {}});` I think you want to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First issue

`weather` is a property of `prop` passed to `Ui` component so you need to either

1. destructure it

```
function Ui({ weather }) {
    console.log(weather.data.main);
    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{weather.data.main}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

2. Or use `props.weather.data.main`.

```
function Ui(props) {
    console.log(props.weather.data.main);
    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{props.weather.data.main}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

## Second issue

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

Now to address the 2nd issue is that, the `weather` property might not be available at the time it was being passed to `Ui` component.

There are also two ways to fix this issue.

1. You can check & display a loading message/gif if the value you'd like to access (`weather.data.main`) is still unavailable or undefined.

(*validating in the child level*)

```
function Ui({ weather }) {
    if (weather === undefined || 
        weather.data === undefined || 
        weather.data.main === undefined)
       return <div>Loading weather data...</div>

    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{weather.data.main}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

2. Or you can render `Ui` only when `Weather` data is available. (It basically depends on where in the component tree you'd like to display the Loading message/gif).

```
function App() {
  // ... rest redacted for brevity
  return (
      // ... rest redacted for brevity

    {weather && weather.data && <Ui weather ={weather}/>}
  )
}
```

That oddly looking `&&` chain instructs that `App` should display only when `weather && weather.data` is available.

Instead of having to use `if` statements I did in the `Ui` components in #1 above, `&&` is just a short-hand.

Comment: Destructuring it doesnt seem to do the trick, still the same error.

Comment: @Kevin.a I am sorry I didn't address the main issue() of `main` not being undefined. I've updated the answer

Comment: @Kevin.a `weather === undefined` will fail if `weather` is `null` which is a common default value (e.g. when using `defaultProps`). It's best to check the truthy case with `weather && weather.data` like in the second example. Or to check the _falsy_ values with something like `!weather || !weather.data` which covers more cases (`null`, `false`, `''` empty string, etc.)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank you for the clarification, Emile. You are right that `weather === undefined` will fail on null value. Probably it's better idea to show that there is "no weather data" should the `weather === null` instead of showing a loading indicator for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Ui({ weather }) {
    console.log(weather.data && weather.data.main);
    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that: `weather.data &&` this will check if `weather` actually has data, and then checks for the `main` inside that data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access weather like this

```
function Ui({ weather }) {
    console.log(weather.data.main);
    return (
        <div className="Ui">
            <h2>{}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially weather is equal to {} whiche doesn't have data.main. Hence you can do the following -

```
{weather.data && <Ui weather ={weather}/>}
```

This will render Ui only when weather.data is available (not before that).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer if you feel it works for you :-)